# Filling null values in timeseries data (for weekends) with previous day values

Tags: sql, database

I have a view with dates, stock name and daily stock prices for weekdays. This excludes data for Saturdays and Sundays.
I want to fill data on Saturdays and Sundays with all the stock names and corresponding stock prices for previous day (Friday).
How can I run a SQL query to get the desired output?

Thank you for your help in resolving this query.

E.g. 
Original data

```
Date       Stock-Name Stock-Price
2019/06/30  null       null
2019/06/29  null       null
2019/06/28  Appl       $200
2019/06/28  Goog       $1100
2019/06/28  Tsla       $300
2019/06/27  Appl       $210
2019/06/27  Goog       $1200
2019/06/27  Tsla       $200
```

Expected Output

```
Date       | Stock Name | Stock Price
--------------------------------------
2019/06/30 |    Appl    | $200
2019/06/30 |    Goog    | $1100
2019/06/30 |    Tsla    | $300
2019/06/29 |    Appl    | $200
2019/06/29 |    Goog    | $1100
2019/06/29 |    Tsla    | $300
2019/06/28 |    Appl    | $200
2019/06/28 |    Goog    | $1100
2019/06/28 |    Tsla    | $300
2019/06/27 |    Appl    | $210
2019/06/27 |    Goog    | $1200
2019/06/27 |    Tsla    | $200
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in values.

To get the preceding value, you can use `lag()` with `ignore null`s for some similar mechanism (not all databases support this functionality).

So:

```
select d.date, s.stockname,
       coalesce(t.price,
                lag(t.price ignore nulls) over (partition by s.stockname order by d.date)
               ) as price
from (select distinct date from t
     ) d cross join
     (select stockname from t where stockname is not null
     ) s left join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.stockname = s.stockname
order by d.date desc, s.stockname;
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=54c2c53b1969032672aa2a006e7fed6f)

**For Postgres:**

With the [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) you are able to get values from next records:

```
SELECT 
    mydate,
    CASE 
        WHEN date_part('dow', mydate) = 6 THEN 
            lead(stock_name) OVER w
        WHEN date_part('dow', mydate) = 0 THEN 
            lead(stock_name, 2) OVER w
        ELSE
            stock_name
    END AS stock_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN date_part('dow', mydate) = 6 THEN 
            lead(stock_price) OVER w
        WHEN date_part('dow', mydate) = 0 THEN 
            lead(stock_price, 2) OVER w
        ELSE
            stock_price
    END AS stock_price
FROM
    stock
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY mydate DESC)
```

This query checks for the current week day using the [`date_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function. The parameter `dow` (day of week) gives out 0 for Sundays and 6 for Saturdays.

If it is Saturday, the `lead()` function only looks one record further and if it Sunday 2 days. Otherwise the original data is taken.

---

**Note:** "Date" is not a  really good column name because it is a reserved keyword in Postgres. To avoid certain problems you should adjust the names a little bit.